# populating textbox from dropdown in php & mysql

Tags: php

I am new in this forum..Forgive me for any kind of mistake & help me.
I have a form with only two fields,first one textfield & next dropdown list.Now I want to show value in list from database based on textfield value from database.i.e If I type perfect username it will show me in dropdown the corresponding emailid(s) of that user.It will change after the username being changed.

Hope someone will help me in this matter.I was working a long time,but cant satisfied.Thanks in advance.This is the code what I have tried.But I want just the reverse.

`    
     function CBtoTB()
     {document.getElementById("username").value=document.getElementById("usernameselect").value}

```
<?php  
$result=mysql_query("select Username from users"); 
$options=""; 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$username=$row["Username"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$username\">".$username.'</option>'; 
} 
?>
<select name="usernameselect" id="usernameselect" onchange="CBtoTB()">
<option value="">&lt; select user &gt;<?php echo $options ?></option>
</select>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>"       size="25" readonly="readonly" />`
```

Answer (score 0):

You option was writen wrongly  please try this :

```
<select name="usernameselect" id="usernameselect" onchange="CBtoTB()">
<option value="">&lt; select user &gt;</option>
<?php echo $options ?>
</select>
```

Comment: so wen user types some thing in text box if it matches the a ny user name you need dropdown box value for corresponding user shold be selected is it correct ?

Comment: If I type perfect username in textbox,it will show me in dropdown the corresponding emailid(s) of that user.If the username is changed in the dropdown, textbox will then show that user's emailid.